# Force knockout foreach binding to update html

Tags: knockout.js

I am having problem with update of foreach binding after drag & drop item from the container:

```
< div id="components-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: components" >.
```

components - observableArray.

Drag & drop affects only HTML, so components stays the same but HTML changes. How can i force foreach binding to re-render components to return HTML to its original state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of Knockout is use ViewModel to drive the display (html), so in your drop event, you should have code components.add(new Component()), and that should update the html.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: The only RELIABLE way i've found to force a view refresh with the foreach binding is this:

```
var tmp = model.foo(); //save the observable current value
model.foo([]);         //assign an empty array to the observable
model.foo(tmp);        //the foreach binding will re-render the list
```

I had a similar issue with an observable array of "page" objects bound to a ul with a "foreach". The foreach binding didn't react to the "reordering" of the pages in the array. It did react *partially* to pushing and removing: it would render / remove the added/removed element but kept the rendered foreach with the same old order. Calling .valueHasMutated() on the observable array didn't work, but the above method did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Call components.valueHasMutated() will force ko to refresh the view.